# Android - Voice Control - Media Intent

Tags: android

I've just started looking at Android development and I'm creating a little application which will map the "Listen to" intent to the media player power amp (recently released api).
This app has no gui it is mearly a glue between Voice control and power amp.

I can catch the intent android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH and control power amp but my issue is that in order to capture android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH I must declare my app as an activity and so when I use Voice Control to send the intent my app loads on the screen. I have tried to declare the app as a receiver\service but I wasn't able to get them to capture the intent.

How can the app run hidden but still capture this intent?

Thanks, Ger.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your needs correctly, you dont actually need any Activity in your app. Just a class that extends BroadcastReceiver and implements the onRecieve(Context, Intent) method of it.

And then in your manifest you can bind that receiver to specific intents you want to listen for. You app will be started without a UI with the entry point being the BroadcastReceiver class you implement.

The manifest entries will look something like:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.music.metachanged" />
                <action android:name="com.amazon.mp3.metachanged" />
                <!-- <action android:name="com.amazon.mp3.playstatechanged" /> -->
                <!-- <action android:name="com.android.music.playbackcomplete" />-->
                <action android:name="com.android.music.playstatechanged" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.music.metachanged" />
                <!--  <action android:name="com.htc.music.playbackcomplete" />-->
                <!--  <action android:name="com.htc.music.playstatechanged" /> -->
                <action android:name="com.sec.android.app.music.metachanged" /> 
                <action android:name="com.nullsoft.winamp.metachanged" />
                <action android:name="com.nullsoft.winamp.playstatechanged" />  
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: I have tried to implement the reciever by using the same intent that I used in the activity

`
     <receiver  android:name=".MusicVoiceControl_BkGrd">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         </intent-filter>
     </receiver>  
`

But when I use Voice Control it can not find the application installed, I am wondering will Voice Control only send the "Listen to" intent to activities!?

Comment: I think you might be right that this intent is not broadcast, but only used with the start-actity notion. The docs at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html suggest a difference between the two.