# How to control Music Player using Voice

Tags: android, voice, audio-player, android-music-player

I'm developing an application, it can control music player using Voice. For example, when i say "play" music player play song, or say "next" music player will play next song, etc..I have Googleed, but didn't find any idea or source code.

Questions:

1. Idea to control Music Player using Voice
2. Source code example.

Thank in advance.

Possible related: [Android - Voice Control - Media Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615798/android-voice-control-media-intent)

Answer (score 0):

You will need this:

```
    private void playNextMusic() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT));
    sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);

    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT));
    sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);

    playPlayMusic();
}

private void playPreviousMusic() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS));
    sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);

    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS));
    sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);

    playPlayMusic();
}

private void playPauseMusic() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE));
    sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);

    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE));
    sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);
}

private void playPlayMusic() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY));
    sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);

    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY));
    sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);
}

private void playStopMusic() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP));
    sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);

    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP));
    sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);
}
```